# Discord Transparent Background

Tags: html, css, discord

I'm just trying to get a background image going on discord and I can't seem to get the default gray to go away. Here is what I have so far:

```
body, .channel-textarea-inner textarea {
    /* using the default discord theme's fonts */
    font-family:
        Whitney,
        'Helvetica Neue',
        Helvetica,
        Arial,
        'Lucida Grande',
        'Meiryo'
}
.app {
    background:url(https://i.imgur.com/xMf3Lzp.jpg) !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
}
/*Transparency*/
#voice-connection,
#friends,
.friends-header,
.friends-table,
.guilds-wrapper,
.guild-header header,
.channels-wrap,
.private-channels .search-bar,
.private-channels,
.guild-channels,
.account,
.friend-table-add-header,
.chat,
.content,
.layers,
.title-wrap:not(.search-bar),
.messages-wrapper,
.messages .divider span,
.messages .divider:before,
.content,
.message-group-blocked,
.is-local-bot-message,
.channel-members-loading,
.channel-members-loading .heading,
.channel-members-loading .member,
.typing{
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

I've read that the .layers bit is what was causing the backgrounds to stop showing previously, but it doesn't appear to work.